# Searching for peers in local network

Tags: networking, udp, ipv6, multicast, ipv4

I want to implement in my program functionality, which will make it able to discover hosts running the same application in local network. To do this I will open in my program an UDP socket and join multicast group at address 224.0.0.1 (when using IPv4) or ff02::1 (when using IPv6). Then I'm going to notify other hosts, that I'm just logged in to this network. I have two question according to my idea:

1. Is it right way to do this or maybe there are better solutions?
2. What's the common policy about using multicast communication in local networks (e.g. hot-spots)? Is it usually possible or most routers block or even doesn't support multicast communication at all?

I develop my appliaction in C++ for Linux, in future I'm ging to write version for Windows in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's usually your best option.  The other option would be UDP broadcast, but there's no guarantee of delivery, so you have to broadcast at a regular interval to make sure the other applications hear it.

As far as policy, I just checked my Linksys Wifi access point, and it had multicast disabled by default.  I suspect a lot of places run in this default configuration

Comment: Another question, will getsockopt() return an error when trying to join multicast group in network, where multicast communication is blocked?

Comment: All UDP sockets, including multicast and unicast, do not guarantee delivery. For discovery the common practice is to broadcast or multicast heartbeat packets.

Comment: Routers will block broadcast and multicast by default but it is irrelevant as the question is about local network discovery, the blocking refers to traffic passed onto the next hop.

Comment: @Steve-o I have currently implemented a discovery using broadcasts. It works inside the "normal" scope of a home LAN (i.e. one integrated AP, Switch, Router from the ISP). I want to change to Multicast now, but if Multicast is disabled does it just use Broadcast or does it not deliver anything?